# what RelativeLayout properties should i use?

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to design a layout for my app as shown below in image

[image: layout to be designed]

but im getting problem which is that the properties im applying for relative layout are not going right as in below my xml code there is horizontal ruler image having centerInParent property and a verticle ruler image also having property of centerInParent by doing this the both rulers come to accurate place but when i put a child above the horizontal ruler or a child toLeftOf verticle ruler they dont appear as the graphical view of xml file shows the reason that although by applying centerInParent the both rulers come to center but their reference remains at edges thats why by using layout_above or layout_toLeftOf the childs go outside of layout

My xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
          android:background="#FFFFFF"
          android:orientation="vertical">

       <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/title"
        >

       <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/icon_img"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
          android:layout_marginTop="2.5dip"
          android:src="@drawable/smicon"
       />
       <TextView  
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon_img"
          android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
          android:text="Welcome To JEM"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:id="@+id/wcm_id"
          android:textSize="18dip"
          android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
       />

      <TextView  
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@id/wcm_id"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
          android:text="APPS BY SAM"
          android:id="@+id/app_by"
          android:textSize="16dip"
          android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      />
     </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- This relative layout which is showing the main cross and icon around it -->
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
     >


    <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/center_hr"
          android:layout_centerInParent="true"
          android:src="@drawable/horizontal"
    />

   <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/center_vr"
          android:layout_centerInParent="true"
          android:src="@drawable/verticle"
   />

  <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_above="@id/center_hr"
          android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/center_vr"
          android:id="@+id/getuser"
          android:src="@drawable/adduser"
  />

 <ImageView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_above="@id/center_hr"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@id/center_vr"
           android:id="@+id/set"
           android:src="@drawable/set"
 />

 <ImageView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@id/center_hr"
           android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/center_vr"
           android:id="@+id/get"
           android:src="@drawable/get"
 />

 <ImageView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@id/center_hr"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@id/center_vr"
           android:id="@+id/ico"
           android:src="@drawable/icon"
 />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

so guys please tell me how can i achive this main cross and icon to lef,right and above,below it as shown in image

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 <ImageView 
android:id="@+id/vertical_ruler"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"/>

<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/imageView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/vertical_ruler"
/>
 <ImageView 
android:id="@+id/horizontal_ruler"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"/>
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/imageView3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/horizontal_ruler"/>
 <ImageView 
android:id="@+id/imageView4"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/vertical_ruler"
android:layout_below="@id/horizontal_ruler"
/>
```

May be it helpful for you..

Answer (score 0):

You could use a TableLayout embedded in a RelativeLayout. The RelativeLayout can be used to center the TableLayout on the screen and in the TableLayout you can add your pictures/buttons and state how many rows and colums you want the TableLayout to have.